# Python - Nested Function, Parentheses order

Tags: python, function

I had a problem where I was required to write a function where if `x` was less than `lo` the output would be `lo` and if `x` was greater than `hi` the output would be `hi`.  Otherwise the output would be `x`.  The solution to the problem was:

```
def hilo(lo, x, hi):

    return min(max(x, lo), hi)
```

Can someone give me an explanation as to the order of the parentheses in the **return** statement?  I tried writing like this:

```
 return min(max(x, lo, hi))
```

but obviously, that didn't work.

Comment: Try to think about that: you're trying to call the [`min` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) with just 1 parameter (return value of the `max` function). That doesn't make a sense (unless that parameter is iterable, which is not your case).

Comment: BTW it's not so much about Python or even programming. It's elementary mathematics. If you have finished the elementary school, you should be able to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

`min(max(x,lo), hi)` means

1. call `max` with `x` and `lo` as parameters.
2. call `min` with *the return value of that call* and `hi` as parameters.

Assuming the semantics of the values `lo` and `hi` and the functions `min` and `max` implied by their names, this logic first figures out which is bigger between `x` and `lo`, and then which is smaller between that and `hi`.   The result is thus guaranteed to be no less than `lo` and no more than `hi`; if `x` is in that range, then `x` itself is returned, otherwise the closest end of the range to `x` is returned.

Whereas, `min(max(x,lo,hi)` means:

1. call `max` with `x`, `lo`, and `hi` as parameters
2. call `min` with the return value of that call as the only parameter.

Given the same assumptions about the names matching the semantics, that makes no sense, as `min` with only one argument, even if it weren't an error, would just return that one argument unchanged. The above would always return whichever is bigger between `hi` and `x`, while `lo` wouldn't enter into it at all.

Answer (score 1):

The function in the innermost parenthesis `max(x, lo)` is executed first. This returns the bigger value between `x` and `lo`. Then the outer function `min` is executed with the remaining 2 arguments `x` or `lo` and `hi`.

The `max` function won't work with 3 arguments as you tried with `max(x, lo, hi)`. Neither does the `min` with 1 argument, what `max` would be returning.